# HTML Table auto sizing

Tags: html

I have a 'table' that I use and since I added text, the width has increased and I can't figure out how to decrease it!

Here's the image

[image]

I need the black table (that holds everything) to be the same width as the orange "upper district" bar. here's the only code I have for it

```
<tr>
<td bgcolor="black" valign="center">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="450">
```

It's a bit better when I remove the text, it's like it's being stretched out to accomodate the text but why does it only stretch a certain amount? And why does it stretch anyway?

Comment: Questions need to include enough code to reproduce the problem (but based on that picture you shouldn't be using any tables, let alone nested ones).

Comment: @RyanMckenna then we can't really help you can we? For us to help you we need to know where and what the problems are.

Comment: @Emz The text is pushing the table to go wider than what it should be, i thought I was just missing a line of code but if not, I must just be doing it completely wrong ( as Quentin pointed out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add css for tr,td,table and set width.

Or add ID to the above and style from there

i.e

```
td { max-width: 50px;}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks :) I don't actually know any CSS so I will go learn that as it's clear I need it!

Comment: No problem. Yeah you should learn it. Just reading the w3c schools tutorial will get you a long way from where you are now. The other thing that will encourage you is that it's nearly as easy as html to pick up.  Do also take note from other comments that using tables to style the type of content you have may not be the most appropriate. Look to use divs and positioning (css). Using tables will work but misrepresents the content on your site as it's not really a table.